# Issue With Objects In PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, class, object

I have a problem with objects in PHP.

http://codepad.org/HdqCVJlw

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
##
class Loader {
    function view() {
        echo 'I did it! )';
    }
}
class Controller {
    public $loader;
    function __construct() {
        $this -> loader = new Loader;
    }
}

##
class Foo extends Controller {
    function index() {
        $this -> loader -> view();
    }
}
```

There are three classes: `Loader`, `Controller` and `Foo`. I want to use method of class Loader in `Foo` class. I know that `__construct()` wouldn't run because `Foo` extends from `Controller`, but anyway I don't get any error.

So how to use that method there with condition that in `Foo` I won't need to write more code?

P.S. I'm creating MVC...

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Your code is working here...

Comment: *(sidenote)* Ask yourself if your Controller really is a specialized Loader. If the answer to that is No, then Controller should not inherit from Loader. If Controller just *uses* a Loader, then you should favor Composition/Aggregation over Inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that `__construct()` wouldn't run because Foo extends from Controller, but anyway I don't get any error.

When instantiating `Foo`, `Controller`'s `__construct()` *will* be run.

The exception is if you make a `__construct()` within `Foo`, and forget to call `parent::__construct()`.

[The code you posted works fine](http://codepad.org/SNzsSKq3).

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to Foo that calls `parent::__construct();`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php